# Always mark message in Drafts folder as read

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I have a gmail account that I access from Thunderbird.
When I write an email and save it as a draft, it gets saved to the Drafts folder. Good. However, this email is marked as unread in the Drafts folder, which I find annoying.
Is there a way to always have the Drafts folder marked as read?

Comment: Me too! I don't think you can fix this. It works in all accounts. There used to be an add-on (which I greatly miss) that added "folder" as a predicate for use in message filter rules. If that was still available, you could probably do it. Probably, the best you can do now is to build a keyboard script that "manually" marks the folder as read when you press a hotkey. You didn't say what OS you are using, but you can look at Windows-AutoHotKey, Linux-AutoKey, Mac-Automator or Maestro.